# Match a node with all the nodes of a subgraph in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, matching, subgraph

I'm having some fun with Neo4j and I need to know how I could find nodes that have a relation with each of the nodes of a given subgraph.

Let's explain this with an example:

(I have around 15000 nodes in my db)

Now, given the subgraph (c1:Thing),(c2:Thing),...(cn:Thing)
I want to know all the nodes that are not any of (c1),...,(cn) but they have a relation with each node of (c1),...,(cn)

In other words I would find Cj where exists the relations:
    (Cj)-[r1]-(c1)
    .
    .
    .
    (Cj)-[rn]-(cn)

And j not in {1, ...., n}

[See this image to see an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu5pC.jpg)

So basically I want to MATCH nodes like c6, those that are connected with each of the nodes of the subgraph (nodes in red).

NOTE: The subgraph given could have any quantity of nodes (n is variable).

My first thought is:

MATCH (c1:Thing)-[r1]-(suggest:Thing), (c2:Thing)-[r2]-(suggest:Thing), .... ,(cn:Thing)-[rn]-(suggest:Thing)
WHERE c1.id=1 AND ..... AND cn.id=n AND NOT(suggest.id IN [1, ...., n])
RETURN c1, r1, ......, cn, rn, suggest;

But that really sucks when we have a "n" that's a big number.

Could you help me?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a way of tackling your question while making some assumptions about your data modeling.

A query similar to this one will likely get you what you want:

```
MATCH p=(n:Thing)-[:RELATED_TO]->(n2), (suggest:Thing)
WHERE n <> n2 AND NOT suggest IN nodes(p) AND ALL (x IN nodes(p) WHERE (suggest)-[:RELATED_TO]->(x))
RETURN suggest
```

Now, this assumes that the subgraph of interest (i.e. c1 to cn) are related by the same relationship.  Of course, you could define the path/subgraph however you like, and even better would be to know your starting and endpoints, but you may or may not have that information handy.  Also, if you're doing multi-length paths/subgraphs, be careful to limit them.  As well if you ARE considering multi-length paths/subgraphs, the results you'll get back will potentially not be unique.

Another assumption is that (suggest) has the same relationship to each node of the subgraph and is of the same type as the relationships in your subgraph.  Tweak this as necessary.

That said, this should be enough to get you started and/or thinking in the right direction.  As always, how you model your data is just as important as how you write your queries, if not moreso.

HTH